# Rescaling the y axis in bar plot causes bars to disappear : R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a barplot using ggplot2, with the y axis starting at a value greater than zero.

Lets say I have the means and standard errors for hypothetical dataset about carrot length at three different farms:

```
carrots<-NULL
carrots$Mean<-c(270,250,240)
carrots$SE<-c(3,4,5)
carrots$Farm<-c("Plains","Hill","Valley")
carrots<-data.frame(carrots)
```

I create a basic plot:

```
p<-ggplot(carrots,aes(y=Mean,x=Farm)) +
   geom_bar(fill="slateblue") +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE,ymax=Mean+SE), width=0)
p
```

This is nice, but as the scale runs from 0 to  it is difficult to see the differences in length. Therefore, I would like to rescale the y axis to something like c(200,300). However, when I try to do this with:

```
p+scale_y_continuous('Length (mm)', limit=c(200,300))
```

The bars disappear, although the error bars remain.

My question is: is it possible to plot a barplot with this adjusted axis using ggplot2?

Thank you for any help or suggestions you can offer.

Comment: [Beware of dynamite!](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/twiki/pub/Main/TatsukiRcode/Poster3.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365167/geom-bar-bars-not-displaying-when-specifying-ylim for more detailed discussions

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try this

```
p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(200,300))
```

Setting the limits on the coordinate system performs a visual zoom; 
the data is unchanged, and we just view a small portion of the original plot.

[image: barplot example]

Comment: If this is what you wanted, consider accepting this as the correct answer by ticking the check under the vote score on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to accomplish the same zoom effect for a **flipped** bar chart, the accepted answer won't work (even though the answer is **perfect** for the example in the question).

The solution for the flipped bar chart is using the argument `ylim` of the `coord_flip` function. I decided to post this answer because my bars were also "disappearing" as in the original question while I was trying to re-scale with other methods, but in my case the chart was a flipped one. This may probably help other people with the same issue.

This is the adapted code, based on the example of the question:

```
ggplot(carrots,aes(y=Mean,x=Farm)) +
  geom_col(fill="slateblue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE,ymax=Mean+SE), width=0) +
  coord_flip(ylim=c(200,300))
```

[Flipped chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7czeW.png)

Comment: one should not have more than one `coord_` layer anyways. If you have added coord_flip to a coord_cartesian call, this clearly can mess things up. Regardless, the "modern" way to flip the coordinates is via switch of the x and y aesthetic, here  `aes(x = Mean, y = Farm)`. Then, you of course need to specify `xlim = ...`