# geom_bar bars not displaying when specifying ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a problem with geom_bars wherein the bars are not rendered when I specify limits on the y-axis.  I believe the following should reproduce the problem:

```
data <- structure(list(RoleCond = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Buyer", "Seller"), class = "factor"), 
                   ArgCond = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No Argument", "Argument"), class = "factor"), 
                   mean = c(2210.71428571429, 2142.70833333333, 2282.40740740741, 2346.2962962963), 
                   se = c(20.1231042081511, 16.7408757749718, 20.1471554637891, 15.708092540868)), 
                   .Names = c("RoleCond", "ArgCond", "mean", "se"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data=data, aes(fill=RoleCond, y=mean, x=ArgCond)) + 
      geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
      geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge, width=0.1, size=.75) + 
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(2000,2500))
```

which gives me this

[image: no bars]

The same code without the limits specified works fine. The geom_errorbar() doesn't seem to be related to the problem, but it does illustrate where the bars should be showing up.

I've tried using `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2000,2500))` which works for limiting the yaxis and getting the bars to display, but the axis labels get messed up and I don't understand what I'm doing with it.

Thanks for any suggestions!  (I'm using R 2.15.0 and ggplot2 0.9.0)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324892/ggplot2-setting-geom-bar-baseline-to-1-instead-of-zero

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could try, with `library(scales)`:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(2000,2500),oob = rescale_none)
```

instead, as outlined [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2-dev/JGal_9nRzsg).

Comment: See also Hadley's response: "I think using squish would be canonical. And this is a valid use, but it does create a deceiving graph." (To expand on the second point: it is generally *not* considered a good idea to use bars when the graph baseline is not at zero ...

Comment: Thanks joran and Ben.  Note for anyone finding this, I had to load 'library(scale)' in order to use the oob parameter.  

I definitely share the concerns with baselines other than 0 on bar graphs in general, but in this case the only possible range of responses was 2000-2500, so I think it illustrates the differences fairly (also, it's what people expect and I'm not feeling brave enough to "do the right thing" at this moment)

Comment: @SamSwift, I believe it's `library(scales)` (with an "s").

Comment: Well, "right thing" could be as simple as using `geom_point` instead of `geom_bar`, in which case there is less conventional expectation that the baseline is at zero ...

Comment: I believe another option would be to use `oob = squish`

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me based on the link shared previously.

```
p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(5,15))
```

Answer (score 12):

Adding an answer for my case which was slightly different in case someone comes across this:

When using `position="dodge"`, the bars get horizontally resized automatically to fill space that is often well beyond the limits of the data itself.  As a result, even if both your `x-axis` and `y-axis` limits are `limits=c(min-1, max+1`, for certain data sets, the `position="dodge"` might resize it beyond that limit range, causing the bars to not appear.  This might even occur if your limit floor is 0, unlike the case above.

Using `oob=rescale_none` in both `scale_y_continous()` AND `scale_x_continuous()` fixes this issue by simply cutting off the resizing done by `position="dodge"`.

As per earlier comment, it requires `package:scales` so run `library(scales)` first.

Hope this helps someone else where the above answers only get you part way.

Comment: Thanks, `oob=rescale_none` in `scale_y_continous()` fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki essentially copying [user teunbrand's canonical answer to that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58956068/7941188) - for more visibility added to this larger thread.

Consider the following plot (`geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`):

```
df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:7],
                 y = 1:7)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col()
g
```

[image]

You can clearly see that the bars look like rectangles. Checking the underlying plot data, confirms that the bars are parameterised as rectangles with xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax parametrisation:

```
> layer_data(g)
  x y PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax colour   fill size linetype alpha
1 1 1     1     1    0    1 0.55 1.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
2 2 2     1     2    0    2 1.55 2.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
3 3 3     1     3    0    3 2.55 3.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
4 4 4     1     4    0    4 3.55 4.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
5 5 5     1     5    0    5 4.55 5.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
6 6 6     1     6    0    6 5.55 6.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
7 7 7     1     7    0    7 6.55 7.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
```

Now consider the following plot:

```
g2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 7))
```

[image]

This one is empty, and reflects the case you have posted. Inspecting the underlying data yields the following:

```
> layer_data(g2)
  y x PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax colour   fill size linetype alpha
1 1 1     1     1   NA    1 0.55 1.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
2 2 2     1     2   NA    2 1.55 2.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
3 3 3     1     3   NA    3 2.55 3.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
4 4 4     1     4   NA    4 3.55 4.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
5 5 5     1     5   NA    5 4.55 5.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
6 6 6     1     6   NA    6 5.55 6.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
7 7 7     1     7   NA    7 6.55 7.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
```

You can see that the `ymin` column is replaced by `NA`s. This behaviour depends on the `oob` (out-of-bounds) argument of `scale_y_continuous()`, which defaults to the `scales::censor()` function. This censors (replaces with `NA`) any values that are outside the axis limits, which includes the 0 which should be the `ymin` column. As a consequence, the rectangles can't be drawn.

There are two ways to work around this. One candidate is indeed as Magnus suggested to use the `ylim` argument in the `coord_cartesian()` function:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 7))
```

[image]

Specifying the limits inside a `coord_*` function causes the graphical objects to be clipped. You can see this in action when you turn the clipping off:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 7), clip = "off")
```

[image]

The other option is to use an alternative `oob` argument in the `scale_y_continuous`, for example `scales::squish`:

```
g3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 7), 
                     oob = scales::squish)
g3
```

[image]

What this does, is that it replaces any value outside the limits by the nearest limit, e.g. the `ymin` of 0 becomes 1:

```
> layer_data(g3)
  y x PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax colour   fill size linetype alpha
1 1 1     1     1    1    1 0.55 1.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
2 2 2     1     2    1    2 1.55 2.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
3 3 3     1     3    1    3 2.55 3.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
4 4 4     1     4    1    4 3.55 4.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
5 5 5     1     5    1    5 4.55 5.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
6 6 6     1     6    1    6 5.55 6.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
7 7 7     1     7    1    7 6.55 7.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
```

Another thing you could do is provide a custom function to the `oob` argument, that simply returns it's input. Since by default, clipping is on, this reflects the `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1,7))` case:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 7), 
                     oob = function(x, ...){x})
```