# How to draw a logarithmic plot with ggplot2 when the numbers are smaller than 1?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a frequency distribution with a long tail and to make better use of the plot real state I draw a logarithmic plot. (The data below is for the sake of presentation)

```
freqs=c(0.7, 0.2, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001)
x=0:(length(freqs)-1)

df=data.frame(x=x, y=freqs)

library("ggplot2")

ggplot(df)  + 
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y),stat =   "identity")+ scale_y_log10()
```

But then since the numbers are smaller than one, the logarithms will be negative and so the bars are upside down. Any way to go around this?

Comment: just shift everything above 1?

Comment: Leave it as-is because it's accurate? Use `scales::log1p_trans`? Use a different transform (square root?)? What result do you want to see? How do you expect the plot to look?

Comment: my suggestion would be *not* to use a bar plot here, just use `geom_point()`; arguably the reason you're having trouble is that you're violating one of the implicit premises of a barplot, which is that the baseline is at zero ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting solution is based on the use of `geom_segment` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324892/ggplot2-setting-geom-bar-baseline-to-1-instead-of-zero).

```
freqs <- c(0.7, 0.2, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001)
x <- 0:(length(freqs)-1)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=freqs)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=1e-4, yend=y), size=35, col="gray30") + 
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1))+ ylab("")+ xlab("") +
scale_x_discrete(limits=c(-.5,4.5))
```

[image]