# Specifying lower limits of a facetted plot with scale="free" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(Taxa=c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
                 Day=as.factor(c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)),
                 Treatment=c(rep(c("t1","t2"),4)),
                 Values=c(100,110,120,130, 120, 130,150, 1800),
                 SD = c(10,11,12,13,12,13,14,200)) # i have one big outlier in the data

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Day, ymax=Values+SD, ymin=Values-SD, y=Values, fill=Treatment))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width=0.7), col="black", width=0.7) +
  facet_wrap(~Taxa, scale="free_y", nrow=2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::scientific) +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.7), col="black", lty="solid", width=0.3)
p1
```

i tried:

```
p1 + expand_limits(ylim = c(100, NA)) # is ignored
p1 + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::scientific, limits = c(100, NA)) # removes geom_bar
p1 + coord_cartesian(ylim=100,NA)  # error
```

I have been asked to start a similar, but more complex plot at a fixed y-value, but let ggplot calculate the x-max individually for each facet. But with `scale="free_y"` is seems to be impossible. Since i have this one big outlier, i do not want to control the ymax globally. Is there a way to achieve this, without plotting all Taxa individually?

Comment: see solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324892/ggplot2-setting-geom-bar-baseline-to-1-instead-of-zero

Comment: Is it possible to leave the upper limits untouched with breaks?

Comment: It was possible to shift the baseline now (without breaks), but how can i use this solution with scale::scientific?