# Stacked bar plot in R with the positive and negative values

Tags: r

I would like to plot a stacked bar plot in R and my data looks as such:

[image]

This table is the values against date and as it can be seen, there are repetitive dates with different sides. I would like to plot a bar plot using this data.

```
combined = rbind(x,y)
combined = combined[order(combined$Group.1),]
barplot(combined$x,main=paste("x vs y Breakdown",Sys.time()),names.arg = combined$Group.1,horiz = TRUE,las=2,xlim=c(-30,30),col = 'blue',beside = True)
```

[image]

Want a stacked plot where I can see the values against dates. How do change my code?

Comment: Please edit your question to add data using `dput` not images. Also is the attached plot the current or expected output?

Comment: Provide example data. When dates are repeated how do you want them to be plotted?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324892/ggplot2-setting-geom-bar-baseline-to-1-instead-of-zero

Comment: You cannot stack positive and negative values.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create this figure with `ggplot2`. 
Here a piece of code for you using a data frame similar to what you have:

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- data.frame(
  date = factor(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8)),
  x = c(-2, 14, -8, -13, 3, -4, 9, 8, 3, -4, 8, -1)
)

g <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = date, y = x)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity", position = position_stack(),
    color = "white", fill = "lightblue"
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

This is the output:

[image]

Obviously, [the official documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_stack.html) is a good way to start to understand a bit better how to improve it.