# How to set the y not from 0 in barplot of ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Normally, the y axis is from 0,

I would like to know how to set the y not from 0, like 3 in the following example, is it possible?

The bar will disappear when set `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3,40))`

Example code

```
 df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
             len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3,40))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61392589/11374827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coord_cartesian`, `scale_y_continuous` will otherwise remove observations that do not fall in the specified range:

```r
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3, 40))
```

[image]